# Can not connect to mssql server on Ubuntu using AD user account

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed a mssql-server (15.0.4335.1-6) on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, following [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16)

Mssql-server is up and running and I can connect using the sa account.

What I want to do, is to connect to my mssql server using Active Directory user accounts. So in order to do that, I joined my ubuntu server machine to my testing environment domain (pvedc.local) using sssd and realmd tools. This is the output of **realm list** command:

*pvedc.local

type: kerberos

realm-name: PVEDC.LOCAL

domain-name: pvedc.local

configured: kerberos-member

server-software: active-directory

client-software: sssd

required-package: sssd-tools

required-package: sssd

required-package: libnss-sss

required-package: libpam-sss

required-package: adcli

required-package: samba-common-bin

login-formats: %U@pvedc.local

login-policy: allow-realm-logins*

Below is my **/etc/sssd/sssd.conf** configuration:

[sssd]
domains = pvedc.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
[domain/pvedc.local]
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = PVEDC.LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
ad_domain = pvedc.local
use_fully_qualified_names = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad

Now I can login to my ubuntu machine using the login tool, or via ssh, using domain user accounts..
Next I created a domain user account so I can use it to connect to my mssql server. So after creating the user account, I created SPN for this account and created the appropriate keytab file, yet again, following [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16).
I changed ownership and permissions on keytab file..

*-r-------- 1 mssql mssql 192 Nov 22 10:43 mssql.keytab*

Next i configured the account to be used for this keytab, using the command
*sudo mssql-conf set network.privilegedadaccount*

and next, i configured mssql server to start using the keytab file for kerberos authentication, using the command
*sudo mssql-conf set network.kerberoskeytabfile /var/opt/mssql/secrets/mssql.keytab*

No error output so far, so I suppose everything is as should be.

Next i connected to mssql server using sa account, and i created a new LOGIN for my ad account (mssqluser@pvedc.local). You can see that the LOGIN is created below (last row)

> SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals;
> GO
> name

---

sa
public
sysadmin
securityadmin
serveradmin
setupadmin
processadmin
diskadmin
dbcreator
bulkadmin
##MS_SQLResourceSigningCertificate##
##MS_SQLReplicationSigningCertificate##
##MS_SQLAuthenticatorCertificate##
##MS_PolicySigningCertificate##
##MS_SmoExtendedSigningCertificate##
##MS_PolicyEventProcessingLogin##
##MS_PolicyTsqlExecutionLogin##
##MS_AgentSigningCertificate##
BUILTIN\Administrators
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
PVEDC\mssqluser

mssqluser can connect to my ubuntu machine using ssh or login. So according to Microsoft documentation now this user is able to connect to my mssql server. But when I try to connect, i get this error:

*root@mssql2:~# sqlcmd -S localhost -U mssqluser
Password:
mssql: login error: Login failed for user 'mssqluser'.
mssql: login error: Login failed for user 'mssqluser'.*

This is the output of mssql error log file (/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog):

*2023-11-22 12:26:53.81 Logon       Login failed for user 'mssqluser'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]*

I even try to connect using SSMS from a remote machine. When i use sa account (SQL authentication) everything is OK. But when I try to connect using mssqluser account I get the error below:

### TITLE: Connect to Server

### Cannot connect to mssql2.pvedc.local\pve3mssql2,1433.

### ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)
For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18452-database-engine-error

### BUTTONS:
OK

And below is the output of mssql error log file, regarding this connection attempt:

*2023-11-22 12:32:03.62 Logon       Error: 17806, Severity: 20, State: 14.
2023-11-22 12:32:03.62 Logon       SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x80090304, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The operating system error code indicates the cause of failure. The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted   [CLIENT: 10.5.5.172]
2023-11-22 12:32:03.62 Logon       Error: 18452, Severity: 14, State: 1.
2023-11-22 12:32:03.62 Logon       Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. [CLIENT: 10.5.5.172]*

I have no clue what the problem would be. I searched the Internet for similar issues and possible solutions and found nothing so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: In the first example, AD logon will not work for localhost unless the fqdn is used. Specifically, 127.0.0.1, localhost, and "." will not work. Ensure you are using the format PVEDC\mssqluser, and try setting the setting disablesssd=true and have SQL use OpenLDAP per the documentation. mssqluser@pvedc.local is not the correct name format. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#additionalconfig

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for answering.
You are right about using localhost. I already used fqdn but i get the same error. I also have the impression that it is not necessary to use the domain part of the account.  Using mssqluser is sufficient, according to documentation:

"Only include the username and not domainname\username or username@domain. SQL Server internally adds domain name as required along with this username when used."

And why would I disable sssd? Microsoft suggest that configuration IF I use other (third party) tools like PBIS, VAS or Centrify.